# [WSO2][ESB] Validation Mediator giving problems although on-fail element has children

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have configured the following validate mediator in my project:

```
            <validate>
            <schema key="gov:custom/testReg/AddressId.json"/>
            <resource key="gov:custom/testReg/AddressId.json" location="default_location"/>
            <on-fail>
                <payloadFactory description="failureResponse" media-type="json">
                    <format>{
                                                   "StatusCode": 0,
                                                   "ErrorCode": "801001",
                                                   "ErrorDescription": "Invalid request parameters, some fields are empty"
                                     }
                    </format>
                    <args/>
                </payloadFactory>
                <respond description="failureResponse"/>
            </on-fail>
        </validate>
```

Yet when I save the API Resource, it throws the following error:

```
A non-empty <on-fail> child element is required for the <validate> mediator
```

I have tried to ignore the errors and proceed to build the project and deploy it however there were errors in the server after it was deployed. 
Can some one help me out on this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use any other validate mediators? When I put this in an API it saves just fine and I get no error codes.  I can imagine actually running it might cause problems because your schema and resource are the same.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. Just to clarify, so you are saying that I must remove the                <resource key="gov:custom/testReg/AddressId.json" location="default_location"/> is it? Also, i don't understand your question on other validate mediators, are you asking whether there are other validate mediators in my API?

Comment: Yes to both. The resource is only used if your schema imports other resources.  And the validator itself seems to work just fine, I don't get any error when put exactly that code into an API and save it. Therefore I wonder if there is another validate mediator that might cause the error.